# Using the tool of asymptotic expansions to solve limit related questions in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, limits, soft-question

I have seen that on math.stackexchange.com lot of people use asymptotic expansions to solve the problem of finding the limit of a sequence.

I am reading from Ross's book on Analysis but he does not introduces it. Are there any sources(web or text) from where I can read about it.

Some illustrations:

$$x^{1/x}=1+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{\log x}{x}\right).$$ can be used to solve $
\lim\limits_{x\to \infty }\left(\sqrt{x}\left(\sqrt[x]{x}-1\right)\right)=0$

$(n+1)^\alpha-n^\alpha$ can be solved by approximating $(1+1/n)^\alpha$ using general binomial theorem.

Comment: I think it’s just standard Taylor series expansions. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @Clayton https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3154638/proving-the-limit-lim-limits-x-to-infty-left-sqrtx-left-sqrtxx-1-r Please read the first comment. He mentions the term "asymptotic expansions". I have seen this term before as well.

Comment: That is just the Taylor series expansion. We have $x^{1/x}=\exp(\log x/x)$. Now expand.

Comment: @Clayton Then how do we decide what terms we have to ignore in the Taylor series expansion.

Comment: You’ll take as many as you need; as $x$ becomes large, $\log x/x\to0$, so you can take as many terms as you want for the desired accuracy. More generally, it depends on the specific context.

Comment: @Clayton Thanks for the discussion. It really helped.